# Vertically align Infragistics TextBoxControl edit areas on Ribbon?

Tags: infragistics, ribbon-control

I have a Ribbon (UltraWinToolbar) with 3 TextBoxTools on it in a Group arranged vertically a bit like:

```
| Short Caption: [xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx] |
| Very Long Caption Indeed: [xxxxxxxxxxx] |
| Tiny: [xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx] |
```

But I want it to look like this:

```
| Short Caption:            [xxxxxxxxxxx] |
| Very Long Caption Indeed: [xxxxxxxxxxx] |
| Tiny:                     [xxxxxxxxxxx] |
```

How can I control the width of the edit area? Using 2010.3

**Update**
This seems to be a result of setting the SharedProps.Width to be a defined value, in my case 100. Setting it to -1 makes the controls line-up, but the edit areas are now a bit small.

Comment: Strange, I have a similar situation and the tools are all of the same length as in your second example. Could you check if the Width property of each tools inside the Instance Props collection is set to -1, same for MinWidth and MaxWidth.

Comment: The widths are all set to 100, if I set them to -1 then they line-up. We want to be able to increase the width you get at -1 to give more room to type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be accomplished using a Creation Filter. Please see the following thread on the Infragistics website for more details and a sample application that demonstrates how you can implement it:

http://forums.infragistics.com/forums/p/68686/347701.aspx

Comment: Thanks, that is my secondary attack at solving this. I think this is the way to go. I will post my answer when I get it working.

Answer (score 1):

I have not a good answer, so if someone has a better way to do, let us all know.

- Right - Click on the UltraToolBarsManager in the component pane and activate the In Place Designer
  option
- Click on the tool placed inside the ribbon
- Move your mouse on the right border of the tool (The mouse icon changes to a
  separator)
- Drag rightward to expand the edit part of the text tool (and reducing the label space)
- Drag leftware to reduce the edit part of the text tool (and increasing the label space)

The same effect can be achieved placing the mouse on the left border of the texttool but inverting the dragging (toward left to increase edit space, toward right to increase the label space)

Comment: Thanks, but my controls are all created programatically from a config file.

Comment: Then I will try to work on the Width and MinWidth property of the tool (Logic suggest to use the Instance Props collection, but Shared Props seems to work always better)

Comment: Yes I noticed that too. Thanks I will experiment with those.